# express service static html referencing js files

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following folder structure in my node project (using node, webpack, and express):

- `dist/` (folder containing .js files)
- `views/` (folder containing static .html files referencing .js files in above mentioned dist folder)

The index.html (located in the above mentioned `views` folder) file contains the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/test.js" ></script>
```

In the app.js for the node application I am serving the static .html page in the following manner:

```
router.get('/setup', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './views/index.html'));
});
```

The problem is that the .html renders properly but it is unable to find the .js file which it references. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `src="./dist/test.js" instead of src="../dist/test.js"`. May be this will be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Inside your app.js file add line:

```
app.use('/source/', express.static(__dirname + '/path_to_js_folder'));
```

And modify your < script > tag as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/source/test.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following -

```
app.use(express.static('dist'));
router.get('/setup', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/hello.html');
})
```

And in your html file just do this -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js" ></script>
```